# Ошибка в билде Google Play Services AndroidManifest

Tags: android, unity3d

Ошибка recources '@integer/google_play_services_version' not foind in AndroidManifest
Поиск решения в интернете ничего не дал

Plugins/Android:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.unity3d.player"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <!--Uncomment to enable vibration-->
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />-->

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <application
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:allowBackup="false">

        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="unity" />
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="false" />

           </activity>

        <meta-data android:name="PUSH_SENDER_ID" android:value="\ XXXXXXXXXXX"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

GooglePlayGames/Plugins/Android/GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- This file was automatically generated by the Google Play Games plugin for Unity
     Do not edit. -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.example.games.mainlibproj"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application>

     <!-- Required for Nearby Connections API -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection.SERVICE_ID"
            android:value="" />

        <!-- The space in these forces it to be interpreted as a string vs. int -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
            android:value="\ #######" />

        <!-- Keep track of which plugin is being used -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.unityVersion"
            android:value="\ 0.9.42" />

        <!-- Build time check to make sure play-services libraries are present -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
       <activity android:name="com.google.games.bridge.NativeBridgeActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Совпадений в файлах нету, после PlayServicesResoler - Android Resolver - Force resolver нашлись файлы библиотеки с одинаковым именем, удалил. Что можно еще сделать?

Comment: Билдите градлом или прям из Юнити?

Comment: да, с помощью градл

Comment: Тогда удалите эту строку вообще. У вас в градл скрипте эти вещи указаны должны быть.

Comment: Удалил, все по прежнему, решением для многих служит 
`The solution you suggested (remove <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@Integer/google_play_services_version" />
from "Assets/Plugins/Android/MainLibProj/AndroidManifest.xml" and put that line into "Assets/Plugins/Android/AndroidManifest.xml" - fixed the problem for me.`
Можете подсказать где Android/MainLibProj найти можно, в проекте и в sdk нету

Comment: В `Assets\Plugins\Android\MainLibProj` лежит.

Comment: Такая директория отсутствует, сразу в AndroidManifest лежит  AndroidManifest
Но подключение идет  package="com.google.example.games.mainlibproj"
Версия SDL Google Play Services 0.9.42

Comment: поправка  /сразу в Assets/Plugins/Android */
Вместо папки MainLibProj есть GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin, в ней AndroidManifest

Answer (score 0):

Повторил эти же действия

`The solution you suggested (remove <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@Integer/google_play_services_version" /> from "Assets/Plugins/Android/MainLibProj/AndroidManifest.xml" and put that line into "Assets/Plugins/Android/AndroidManifest.xml" - fixed the problem for me.`

только с директорией `Assets/GooglePlayGames/Plugins/Android/GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin/AndroidManifest.xml`, вместо `Assets/Plugins/Android/MainLibProj/AndroidManifest.xml`

Далее появилась следующая ошибка `The attribute application@allowBackup = false in:Google:colliders wih another value`

ее решением послужило `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873066/how-to-remove-shared-preference-while-application-uninstall-in-android/35296675`

или

`android:allowBackup="true"`